# Outlook 2013 rules do not work after migrating mailbox to Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, outlook

About a month ago I added Exchange 2013 to my org and migrated my box to it (from Exchange 2010). At that point my rules completely stopped working automatically. If I ran them manually they worked fine.

Another user's mailbox I migrated works fine. However, this box didn't have any rules until after the migration and me discovering that my own rules no longer worked.

I have tried:

- deleting and recreating the rules from Outlook 2013;
- deleting and recreating the rules from OWA;
- starting Outlook with /cleanrules and recreating them;
- deleting/disabling and creating/enabling rules from Exchange Management Shell;
- turning off and on Cached Exchange Mode in Outlook.

Nothing has worked and I'm not even sure what to try next.

edit: By the way, these are basic rules like moving emails upon arrival to different folders based on keywords in the subject and/or the sender.

edit2: Why is this being voted for closure?

Comment: Regarding the close votes: I suspect it's because people have a knee-jerk reaction concerning questions that prominently feature Outlook. *"User issue, RAWR!"*

Comment: I was afraid of that but I tried at superuser first and got nothing. It seems to me that this is a problem in my mailbox or with the Exchange database; something deeper than Outlook anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for forgetting about this post but I did find a solution in October of 2013.

For some reason my mailbox had been set as the Journal Report NDR destination and, beginning with Exchange 2013, mailbox and transport rules do not get processed for the mailbox with this assignment.

This can be fixed with Exchange Management Shell and the following commands (first to verify, then to reassign):

```
PS> Get-TransportConfig | Select JournalingReportNdrTo
PS> Set-TransportConfig -JournalingReportNdrTo <new_email_address>
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely have hidden (broken) rules in the mailbox.  Try using [MFCMAPI](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) to clear them out.

Launch MFCMAPI, and select *Session -> Logon*.  Browse to *Top of Information Store -> Inbox* and right-click and select 'Open Associated Content Table'. You're looking for messages with the message class `IPM.Rule.Message`.  Remove those using the DELETE_HARD_DELETE delete option.

(Note that doing this will remove all of your rules.  You may want to just go looking for one that looks out-of-place or broken.)

Comment: It didn't work. I've been working with Microsoft on this issue and have used this tool at their direction though they haven't specifically asked me to do this. They collected a lots of diagnostic info and logs but still don't know what the problem is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

For Exchange environment:

1. On the root of your mailbox, right click any black place, select Properties > button Advanced
2. Go to the Advanced tab , and disable “Cached Exchange Mode”.
3. Press Win + R keys, type outlook.exe /cleanrules, and press Enter.
4. restart outlook

Once you have done any of the above methods, re-create the rule to check if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the catch all for Journal NDR fixed my problem as well.  Instead of PS I used the GUI/ECP. Compliance Managemente > Journal Rules Tab > Send undeliverable journal reports to:

Answer (score -2):

This has helped me out greatly and one thing to add is I am using Office 365 and these commands were exactly what I needed.

Apologies for forgetting about this post but I did find a solution in October of 2013.

For some reason my mailbox had been set as the Journal Report NDR destination and, beginning with Exchange 2013, mailbox and transport rules do not get processed for the mailbox with this assignment.

This can be fixed with Exchange Management Shell and the following commands (first to verify, then to reassign):
PS> Get-TransportConfig | Select JournalingReportNdrTo
PS> Set-TransportConfig -JournalingReportNdrTo